# Fragment dose not appear when data come from json

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

I have two `Fragment` in the same view, fragments retrieve json data in horizontal recycleview.

I open my first fragment from `MainActivity`.

AND i can open fragments from first fragment, but i can't open fragments from first `fragments` if the 2nd `fragment` retrieve from `json`.

My code below is in my first `fragment` that i opened from `MainActivity`.

MainFrog.class

```
public class MainFrog extends Fragment {

// CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
private static final String TAG = "MainFrog";
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private RecyclerView mRVMainFrog;
private AdapterMain mAdapter;
String url = "URL";
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray sectionArr = null;
String sections = "sections";
String sectionName = "section_name";
Context context;
TextView searchOnSelect;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Make call to AsyncTask
    new AsyncLogin().execute();
}


private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {

            sectionArr = json.getJSONArray(sections);

            // looping through All Items
            Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: " + sectionArr);
            for (int i = 0; i < sectionArr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = sectionArr.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: " + c);
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String name = c.getString(sectionName);
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: " + name);
                //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                //map.put("", name);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                data.add(String.valueOf(name));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    //              
  //`RecyclerView chipRecyclerView =` 
   // (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mAdapter = new AdapterMain(getActivity(), data);
        // updating listview
        //mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

        mRVMainFrog.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRVMainFrog.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}


Fragment fragment;

public MainFrog() {


}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View inflatedMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainfrog, null);
    View infaltedMain = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    View mainLayout = infaltedMain.findViewById(R.id.detailsContent);
    mRVMainFrog = (RecyclerView) inflatedMainView.findViewById(R.id.mainRecycleView);
    searchOnSelect = (TextView) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.searchOnSelect);
    ItemClickSupport.addTo(mRVMainFrog).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
            // do it
            if (position == 0) {
                fragment = new CarFrog();
                replaceFragment(fragment);
                searchOnSelect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (position == 1) {
                fragment = new BuildFrog();
                replaceFragment(fragment);
                searchOnSelect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (position == 2) {
                fragment = new DeviceFrog();
                replaceFragment(fragment);
                searchOnSelect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (position == 3) {
                fragment = new DeviceFrog();
                replaceFragment(fragment);
                searchOnSelect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    return inflatedMainView;
}
```

and my replaceFragment look like :

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.carLayout, someFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack("abc");
    transaction.commit();
}
```

`repkaceFragment` method replace with 2nd `layout` below first `layout`, 
but when i replace it with first  layout (firstfragment) it's work

The 2nd fragment work perfect when open from static data, but when `position == 0`
it dosen't work.

```
CarFrog.class
```

have same code i used in `MainFrog.class`

In My `Log` `CarFrog.class` retrieve data very well but the `fragment` dosen't appear.

**UPDATE**:

after debug on opening `CarFrog` mAdapter return null.?

[recycleView return null too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA1BM.png)

but in cases it's return null when i open `MainFrog` but it's work there.

Comment: where is mRVMainFrog declared?

Comment: at the top @ZakiPathan

Comment: call new AsyncLogin().execute(); in onCreateView after layout items declared. and remove `RecyclerView chipRecyclerView =` 
    (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView); from AsyncTask. try this @ibrahimali

Comment: check my answer below @ibrahimali

Comment: please check Update

Answer (score 0):

What does the Log say if you can upload it it would help.
i think your trying to touch UI thread from an asyntask and it's not possible, 
in that case you need to surround yourself with do in ui thread.

again without the log it's a bit hard to guess as this is a very general question.

maybe try to see when data was received then when this flag has been on call a function who will run on UI thread and will upload the new Fragment to the view

Comment: yea data received very well and the fragment opened but with logic error so

Answer (score 0):

call `new AsyncLogin().execute();` in `onCreateView` after layout items declared. and remove `RecyclerView chipRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);` from `AsyncTask`. Remove `onCreate` because fragment have `onCreateView` So add `new AsyncLogin().execute();` in `onCreateView`

```
 mRVMainFrog = (RecyclerView) inflatedMainView.findViewById(R.id.mainRecycleView); 
//Execute AsyncTask here
 new AsyncLogin().execute();
```

Hope this helps you. if any problem still there feel free to ask.

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper you getting any error? please debug and check on which line the main problem is

Comment: who are you @AndroidDeveloper? this question is not asked by you